# canonical livepatch error: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I'm using livepatch on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for quite some time. A few days ago I noticed a red exclamation mark.
Then I signed out and tried to reapply the live patch.

However the following comand throws an error:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable <key>
--> error executing enable: failed to register client: Post https://livepatch.cannonical.com/v1/client/<key>?test=: x509: certificate signed by unknown autority.
```

How can succesfully enable live patch again? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When was the last time you updated the server manually? If your system is suffering from [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+bug/1790520), then a fix was released last August 

Comment: when SW update show up in grahical client I always apply them asap. Currently graphical client doesn't show any pending updates. Should I do anything else?

Comment: Did you type that error yourself? The URL should begin with `https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/` (single `n` in `canonical`).

Comment: yes, it's my typo. Thanks for mentioning it.
I just now tried apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and then sudo canonical-livepatch enable <key> --> same error.
So system should be up to date.

Comment: Is it an issue with my ubuntu installation or should I register online for a new livepatch key?